# Html.DropDownList with Ajax call to fill partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in my page: (results is a div)

```
  <% 
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("MembersByClubSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
    { 
      %>
      <%= Html.DropDownList("ddlClubs", new SelectList(Model.ClubNameList, "ClubID", "ClubName"), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>
      <%
    }
  %>
```

My Action is

```
public ActionResult MembersByClubSearch(string query)
    {
members = ... // code to get the List<> of members

      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        return View("MembersByClubSearchResultUserControl", members);
      }
      else
      {
        return View(members);
      }
    }
```

But the submit of my dropdownlist isn't an AjaxRequest.
When I use a submit button, it works fine, but I want to submit when the user changes the dropdown instead of changing dropdown AND clicking a button.

Any ideas?

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to get rid of MSAjax and use jquery along with the [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MembersByClubSearch", "Home")) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedClubId, 
        new SelectList(Model.ClubNameList, "ClubID", "ClubName"), 
        new { id = "club" }
    ) %>
<% } %>
```

And in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    // Ajaxify the form => this is for normal submit
    $('form').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        $('#results').html(result);
    });

    // When the value of the dropdown changes force an ajax submit
    $('#club').change(function() {
        $('form').ajaxSubmit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `this.form.submit();` javascript function performs a traditional HTTP POST on your form. You need to send an AJAX style POST to your controller instead in order to trigger the `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` statement.

I would use JQuery and the $.post() function, which allows you to specify a callback function to update your partial view.

There is a good example here that may help you: [Dynamic-Select-Lists-with-MVC-and-jQuery](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Dynamic-Select-Lists-with-MVC-and-jQuery.aspx)